# Misleading food labelling

Tags: canada, consumer-protection

What to do if you were violently ill from a product from a huge establishment that had a lone, large green label on the front of the product saying “vegan”, only to find once consuming, it contained heavy cream, eggs, butterfat and milk in it? There was an entire shelf of products mislabelled.

Comment: You find a lawyer and have them determine if indeed there was mislabeling.